# Ceiling fan speed control

Tags: remote-control, speed

I have heard it said that a ceiling fan with a built in three speed manual switch should be set on the high speed setting when using an electronic speed control.  I have not found an answer as to why this is.  Is this a true statement or can the manual switch be set on a slower speed and also have the electronic control set to a lower speed as well?

Answer (score 2):

If the manual switch is set to the slower speed, then the electronic control will only be able to increase the speed up to that lower speed. If the manual switch is set to the higher speed, the electronic control will be able to adjust the speed over the entire range.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Johan.  I forgot to state my concern with using the remote speed control.  I don't recall where I heard this but it was stated that using an electronic speed control, on a medium or low setting, when the fan manual switch is set to a low or medium speed, it could cause overheating of the motor winding.  I'm not sure if this is true or not.